# Item is being selected in ListView on page load

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-store-apps

I have a `ListView` in my xaml, and it's ItemsSource and SelectedItem property is binded to a ViewModel.

**Xaml**

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding SitesCollection}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSite, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding url}"></TextBlock>
         </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

**ViewModel**

```
public ObservableCollection<AWRestrictedSite> _SitesCollection;
public ObservableCollection<AWRestrictedSite> SitesCollection
{
     get
     {
          //populate collection
          return _SitesCollection;
     }
}

public AWRestrictedSite _SelectedSite;
public AWRestrictedSite SelectedSite
{
      get
      {
          return _SelectedSite;
      }
      set
      {
          _SelectedSite = value;
          //do some stuff
      }
 }
```

For some reason when the page loads, it selects the first item in the ListView. Here is what happens when the page loads:

1. Get inside SitesCollection is being called, (which populates the listview and returns the collection).
2. Get inside SelectedSite is called, which returns null
3. Set inside SelectedSite is called which sets the value to the first item

Does anyone know why this could be happening?

Comment: That's weird. I have a control that look pretty much exactly the same as this one, and nothing is selected initially. Maybe something happens that sets the `SelectedSite` to not null during initialization?

Comment: Hmm, yeah somehow SelectedSite is being set during initialization. I've double checked and I'm not doing anything on my side with setting the SelectedSite.

Comment: Actually, I think I figured out why. It has to do with the way my app is set up. I have a TextBlock and a button on a different page. When you press the button or press enter on the text box it takes you to this page (with the listview). And this error (with the item being selected) only happens when enter is pressed. So I think it has something to do with the enter key still somehow being pressed when the page loads, thus selecting the item.

Answer (score 0):

Its a two way bind, and when loaded, `ListView` (I think) selects the first item in its bound collection. Try adding a `Loaded` method to the `ListView` and setting the `SelectedItem` in there. This should happen *after* the first item is selected.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when we set the `SelectedItem` of a `ListView` to `ItemsSourceCollection.FirstOrDefault()`